# What is the most efficient way to manage changes my product comparison tables?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, table

I have a site that features tables comparing products over hundreds of pages. Many of these products appear multiple times and I originally made these tables static, and now need a more efficient way to manage them.

For example, if 'Product 1' has a change in price, I'd like to just have it so I can edit the price and it will reflect it in all tables featuring 'Product 1' across the site.

I can already think of some solutions such as custom post types, taxonomies and PHP, but I was hoping to get some insight and suggestions from others before I invest into another inefficient management method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a value to update across all tables, you should look at [foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html). They are designed to be updated once but spread across tables.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest doing pretty much what you'd alluded to; if you have products which have information attached to them and are being displayed in multiple locations, then a good way to go about it would be a custom post type with a custom field for "price". The "Types" plugin is one decent way to go about this relatively easily, allowing for you to edit this in a prettier way than the Wordpress custom fields editor.

The real question, then, is whether you'd be able to display that information easily in the way that you'd like. A taxonomy attached to that post type would allow you to display all of the products with a particular term (e.g. "yellow widgets") attached, which may or may not meet your needs.

Certainly this is a better solution, if you have lots of products, then simply entering the information in pages and then just version-controlling the crap out of it.